# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined at HTMLSelectElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using jQuery to clone a table body with the following script:

```js
//1. Add new row
$("#addNew").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
  var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
  var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

  var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
  $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
  $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function(i, val) {
    // Replaced Name
    var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
    var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
    $(this).attr('name', newN);
    //Replaced value
    var type = $(this).attr('type');
    if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
      $(this).attr('value', '');
    }

  });
  $trLast.after($trNew);
});

// 2. Remove
$('a.remove').live("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

I'm trying to clone the following:

```html
<tr style="border:1px solid black">
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].WarmUp)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].ExerciseName)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].CoolDown)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].MomentOfTheDay)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].ExerciseWeek)</td>
    <td><select asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<SampleMvcApp.Models.Days>()"></select></td>
    <td>
        @if (j > 0)
        {
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
        }
    </td>
```

However it works well when I only have all the `HTML.TextBox` or any other text inside the  `<td>` tag, but when I add

```html
<select asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<SampleMvcApp.Models.Days>()"></select>`
```

it stops working.

Getting the error at

```js
var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<select>` tag (included in jQuery's [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector) doesn't have a `name` attribute, so `$(this).attr('name')` will be undefined for that tag.

Therefore `oldN` will also be undefined, hence the error.

Add a `name` attribute to your `<select>` tag, or search for actual `<input>` tags instead of `:input` to limit yourself to text boxes:

```
$.each($trNew.find('input:text'), function (i, val) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working now! And it's way cleaner with that change on the find.